# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Flashloader.Controller'

Tags: c#

Can someone help me with this, I can't figure out what i should do.
This is the error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'Flashloader.Controller'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

This is my source:

```
public partial class NewApplication : Form
{

    private toepassinginifile _toepassinginifile;
    private controllerinifile _controllerinifile;



    //private controllerinifile _controlIniFile;

    public Toepassing toepassing = new Toepassing();

    public NewApplication( toepassinginifile iniFile)
    {
        _toepassinginifile = iniFile;
        _controllerinifile = new controllerinifile();

        controllerComboBox.DataSource = _controllerinifile.Controllers;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Srec Files (.a20; .a21; .a26; .a44)|*.a20; *.a21; *.a26; *.a44|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        openFileDialog1.Title = ("Choose a file");
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileBox.Text = (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toepassing.Name = nameBox.Text;
   ---->#toepassing.Controller = controllerComboBox.SelectedItem;#
        toepassing.TabTip = descBox.Text;
        toepassing.Lastfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        fileBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;


        if (nameBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Name");
        else if (controllerComboBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Controller");
        else if (descBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Desciption");
        else if (fileBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Applicationfile");
        _toepassinginifile.ToePassingen.Add(toepassing);
        _toepassinginifile.Save();

        MessageBox.Show("Save Succesfull");



        this.Close();
    }
}
```

How to i fix this, can could not find the problem because i want to connect my combobox to my ini file and the function for that i allready have but in some way i get this error.

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: Its already fixed but thanks

Comment: yes but that does not help others that comes here from a search engine

Comment: i got he error where it is STRONG

Comment: i got the error where the arrow point to

Comment: that's better and when posting it's often better to post a short self contained complete example (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, do write an explicit conversion:

```
toepassing.Controller = (Flashloader.Controller)controllerComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a safe cast.

Something like

```
toepassing.Controller = controllerComboBox.SelectedItem as Flashloader.Controller;
```

Have a look at [as (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The as operator is used to perform certain types of conversions
>   between compatible reference or nullable types.
>
> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion
>   is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

What is nice about the as operator, is that you can test the variable for null afterwards to see if the cast was successfull, whereas the direct cast will throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: Why use a safe cast? it would seem that it's indeed an error if the cast fails so if using a safe cast why not then also handle the error instead of masking it in a `null`?

Comment: I have added my reasoning to the answer.